# How to remove a reference of task details with an external reference in planner using the beta Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm newbie to the Microsoft Graph API and I want to use it to remove a reference (link) of a task details in planner.

As part of the updating a task details I use the externalReferenceCollection and to perform the update I follow the link below: http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/taskdetails_update

Documentation from Microsoft also says that: "Properties of an Open Type can be defined by the client. In this case, the client must provide valid URLs based on the HTTP/HTTPS protocols as properties and their values must be the externalReference objects. Based on OData, property names in Open Types cannot contain the following characters: ., :, % so they need to be encoded. Example is shown above. **To remove a reference, set the value of the property to null**"

But I'm not sure how to set the value of property to null to build up a JSON string to remove a reference (link) of a task details.

PS: I'm using HttpClient in C# and the way to update a task details is similar to this class: https://github.com/OfficeDev/TrainingContent/blob/master/O3653/O3653-15%20Microsoft%20Graph%20for%20Planner%20and%20Tasks/Completed%20Solutions/Exercise3/Office365PlannerTask/Office365PlannerTask/Models/MyTasksRepository.cs

Thanks in advance!

Tuan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've figured out the answer. I post here so it should help.

To remove a reference with the url is "http%3A//2%2Eff%2E2%2E1" for instance, the request body JSON of the references should look like as below:

```
{"description": "task description 1", "references": { 
"http%3A//2%2Eff%2E2%2E1": null
}}
```

Happy coding!